# Python, overiding itself

Tags: python, oop, class

I've a following problem. I have a model class in MVC and it has a special purpose. In certain cases it should be able to override itself. Is this kind of behavior possible?

```py
Class Text(Document):
    a =  StringField()
    b =  StringField()

    def save(self):
        if 1==Text.object(a=self.a).count():       # if similar object exists in db,
             self = Text.object(a=self.a).first()  # get the instance from db and
                                                   # override the origian class.
        else:                                      #use super class' save-function
             return super(Text, self).save()
```

Comment: Even if there is a way to do that, is that really what you want to maintain and understand in 6 months from now? Instead of - create the object - ask the db if there is a similar one - substitute the object Why don't you - ask the db if it has an object with some given properties - fetch it if yes or create it otherwise ?

Comment: This would make the coding easier. Since the low-level db-model is taking care of all saving functions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no trivial way for an object to *become* another object in python.  Assigning to `self` won't do this; `self` is a local variable in the method definition, And assigning to it won't change the existing instance in any way; only make it inaccessible for the rest of the method.

There are a few ways to approach this problem.  The preferred way is to have a method that returns the correct instance.

```
class Foo(...):
    def get_or_save(self):
        existing = load_from_database(self.bar)
        if existing is not None:
            return existing
        else:
            save_to_database(self)
            return self

new_inst = Text()
new_inst.bar = "baz"

inst = new_inst.get_or_save()
# stop using new_inst
```

There is also a hackish way to get a similar effect to your original example.  Ordinary python classes store most of their attributes in a special `__dict__` attribute.  You can copy that and it will be as though one instance is replaced by the other.  Of course, that only works for perfectly plain python classes, and may or may not work classes defined in an ORM, or which retain state in more clever ways.

```
class Foo(...):
    def save(self):
        existing = load_from_database(self.bar)
        if existing is not None:
            self.__dict__ = existing.__dict__
        else:
            save_to_database(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible :-)

Seriously, using a conditional call to `super` as in your example will achieve the result.

However, the style of your example is a little confusing, and changing it may allow you to achieve your overall objectives more easily.  (But neither of these directly affects your question.)

1. I would not recommend putting a method in your class called `object` unless I had no other choice.
2. The fact that you are passing `self.a` to `Text.object`, within method `Text.save`, doesn't seem right.  It would be cleaner to simply call `self.object()` and have method `object` use `self.a` directly in its code.

Comment: it looks like Django code for looking some object with `a == self.a`

Comment: `self = Text.object(a=self.a).first()` doesn't do what he wants it to do. It just points `self` at that object _for the rest of that method call_, it doesn't change the object in other scopes -- it doesn't "override the original class". His call to `super` is only when no "similar object exists in db" so it is unrelated to the re-assignment of `self`.

Comment: Any ideas how to replace the original object with the object which will be fetch from database? I also noticed that getting object and placing it to self, won't work.

Comment: I think you're struggling with language concepts.  Maybe it will help you to take a break and go through the Python Tutorial included in the official documentation.  Your assignment to `self` in the code you posted only lasts as long as the lifetime of that method.  That's because `self` is a local variable to that method.

Comment: I've no idea how to do that, assigning self-variable was just a clumsy way to express the problem.